# MySQL database username

Tags: mysql

What is database user, in what kind of relation is it to MySQL user (root) with which I login into MySQL command line client?

How can I see the list of all users out there, list of all their privileges over certain database? And how can I view it all in one place (without typing commands)?

If I make a database on one PC, export it, and transfer that file on a different machine, what happens with users?

Answer (score 1):

The information is available from the following tables:

```
mysql.users
mysql.db
```

The `users` table has global privileges (over all databases), the `db` table has the privileges on individual databases. (There can also be object level privileges, those are in another table in the mysql schema.)

You can use mysqldump to retrieve the information in these tables, pull out the INSERT statements for the rows you want to "import". After inserting rows to those tables, make those changes effective by having MySQL re-read the contents of those tables, using the FLUSH PRIVILEGES statement.